# Inequality for subordinate norm of a submatrix : $\Vert B\Vert\le\Vert A\Vert$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

We 'did' this exercise in class

> Show that the subordinate norm of a submatrix is smaller than the the subordinate norm of the matrix i.e. $$\Vert B\Vert\le\Vert A\Vert$$ where $B$ is the sub matrix of $A$.

*The solution was* :

The main idea is to write $B=M_1AM_2$ with $\Vert M_h\Vert\le1$ for $h=\{1,2\}$ with it easy to conclude.
We only said $M_1,M_2$ is the matrices with entries $1$ on the rows and columns of $A$ contained in $B$ and $0$ elsewhere but we did not wrote specifically the matrix $M_1$ and $M_2$.

**Question 1:** Can we write *pecifically the matrix $M_1$ and $M_2$?

**Question 2**: We used the inequality for subordinate norm the matrices must be square matrices, Is it possible to deal with non-square matrices?

Comment: Give me an example of a matrix $A$ and a submatrix $B$, and I'll tell you what the appropriate $M_i$ are.  However, the $M_i$ will look different depending on what $A$ and $B$ are and how $B$ fits into $A$.  The same inequality will hold for non-square matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why we cannot write $M_i$? perhaps we can write $M_i$ is 'function' of $A$ and $B$? Can you explain how can we will proceed for non-square matrices? Thanks

Comment: We can write the $M_i$ as a function of "which submatrix" we've chosen from $A$.  Do you understand what I mean if I say "let $I$ be the set of rows chosen to make $A$" and "Let $J$ be the set of columns chosen to make $A$"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think : In other words your a 'dividing' $A$ on rows or columns such that all these rows(or columns) are  $A$.

Comment: Sorry I mean the rows/columns used to make $B$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, could you help me prove $||M|| \leq 1$ ?

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna if you want help with this, you should post a new question that refers to this one. The quick answer, however, is to note that $M^2=M$.

Comment: M need not be square right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the set of rows chosen to make $B$ from $A$ and let $J$ be the set of columns chosen to make $B$ from $A$.  We define $M_1,M_2$ by
$$
M_1[i,j] = 
\begin{cases}
1 & i = j \in I \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
M_2[i,j] = 
\begin{cases}
1 & i = j \in J \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: +1 to make this clear in my 'head' ;P. Anyway can you share how can we proceed (for the inequality only) if $A$ is a non-square matrix?

Comment: If $A$ is $m \times n$, then $M_1$ should be $m \times m$, and $M_2$ should $n \times n$.  They're constructed in the same way.